# Gnome Flashback desktop icons stuck in "auto arrange icons"

Tags: gnome, 20.04, desktop-environments, gnome-flashback

I installed 20.04, did the updates, and ran `sudo apt-get install gnome-session-flashback`. I like the flashback feel. Then I did the updates again.

The issue is that I cannot move the desktop icons. If I try to drag and drop an icon from where it currently is, to another location on the desktop, it snaps back to it's original location as soon as I release the mouse button.

When I right click on the desktop, and go to "Placement", the other options I am interested in are greyed out:

[image]

When I use dconf-editor, and select the other options, as soon as I select the other option, it reverts back to the default option. Also it doesn't help if I run `sudo dconf-editor`:

[image]

Also I tried `sudo gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-flashback.desktop.icons placement align-icons-to-grid` but as you can see it didn't help:

[image]

Any ideas are really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-flashback/-/issues/41

Comment: @muktupavels Thanks for the link. I read it, and I understand that at present this is the only available behavior. Do you have an estimate of how long before the other options are available?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have ETA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The developer offered a link that shows that at this time, this is the only implemented behavior for the flashback session. Link: [gnome-flashback issue #41](http://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-flashback/-/issues/41) Thanks.